# how to check whether Button is clicked or not

Tags: java, android

I have to check whether the button is clicked or not.if clicked application has to do one task and if not, application has to do another task. I tried to do this, but I am getting no connection error which I have put at the end of the code in catch block.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PracticeVO practiceObj;

    try {

        setTitle("Klarity");
        setPrefBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setPrefBtn);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_klarity_home);

        /*
         * asynchronous calls
         */

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        final ConnectionHelper con = new ConnectionHelper();
        /*
         * It will connect to DB and fetches the Practice Information
         */
        if (Btnclicked == false) {

            String allPracticesStr = null;
```

here I have set the boolean variable 'Btnclicked' true.

```
 setPrefBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Btnclicked=true;
                    Intent setPrefIntent = new Intent(KlarityHome.this,
                            SetPreferences.class);
                    startActivity(setPrefIntent);

                }
            });
```

But After executing this The cursor is directly goin here and displaying 'no connection'.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "There is some error in application";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        System.out.println("no connection");
    }

}
```

Anyone has solution on this.

Comment: Replace `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);` with `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ex.toString(), duration);` and tell us what the Toast shows..just for debugging.

Comment: I think you have an NPE..check if you have initialised `Btnclicked `.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
//This is the toast msg

Comment: Yes I have initialised Btnclicked at class level.

Comment: Yes that is what i have said...I'll add my answer...just 1 min..

Comment: Please see my answer...just add `Btnclicked=false;` or `Btnclicked=false;` before the `if` loop or you just replace `Boolean Btnclicked;` to `Boolean Btnclicked=false;`.

Comment: Did you check the answer @Aditya ?

Answer (score 2):

as you said

> "the button is clicked or not.if clicked application has to do one task and if noapplication has to do another task"
>   so, if i were you, i'll put 2 radio buttons, every one with the text of the task you want to do, and add a listener for them, like this:

```
radiobutton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            radiobutton2.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

radiobutton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                radiobutton1.setChecked(false);
            }
    });
```

and last, in the button do the task you want to do:

```
    Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
    if(radiobutton1.isChecked){
    //do task 1
}else{
//do task2}
    }
    });
```

Comment: Yes radio button can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `NPE(NullPointerException)` since you havent initialised `Btnclicked` in your code at the time of usage.ie you are checking whether `Btnclicked` is false like

```
if (Btnclicked == false) {
```

But at the time of this checking, the value of `Btnclicked` is `null` and hence an NPE.

So to get rid of this, you just add either

```
Btnclicked=true;
```

or

```
Btnclicked=false;
```

before the `if` loop according to your logic.

**OR**

or just replace the declaration from `Boolean Btnclicked;` to `Boolean Btnclicked=false;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made changes according to you. but still I am getting the NPE.But the only change is I am able to populate spinner with data from server. And the intent is not working.ie After click it should go to next activity.= which is not going

Comment: Have you declared `SetPreferences` in Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Btnclicked you don't need that. `OnClickListner` is meant for what you're trying to do. The code which you want to run when button is not pressed put it before

```
//When button is not pressed
setPrefBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //When button is pressed
                }
            });
```

And the code which you want to run when the button is clicked place it inside the `onClick(){}`